# swift how to parse complex json?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

[image]
Here is my method for parsing JSON

```
var apiUrl = NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/api.php")
var apiData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(apiUrl, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached, error: nil)

var apiJson = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(apiData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)
```

`http://127.0.0.1/api.php` url returned data.

```
{
    "tit":"服务器",
    "loc":[
        {
            "_name":"北京",
            "evn":"funckEvent:"
        },{
            "_name":"英国",
            "evn":"funckEvent:"
        },{
            "_name":"日本",
            "evn":"funckEvent:"
        },{
            "_name":"发过",
            "evn":"funckEvent:"
        },{
            "_name":"中国",
            "evn":"funckEvent:"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to loop json arrays ?
I would like to cycle to print the contents of the brackets`{"_name":"中国","evn":"funckEvent:"}`

`var loc = apiJson.objectForKey("loc")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code works perfectly fine for me (running a `localhost` server serving that exact JSON at 'json.html'); however, it failed to print until I specified the specific port (in my case, `NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/json.html")`).  Have you tried explicitly specifying the port?

Furthermore, it may be enlightening to actually catch the error returned by `dataWithContentsofURL` by declaring an NSError variable and passing it in, like so:

```
var error: NSError?
var apiData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(apiUrl, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached, error: &error)
```

To loop over an element here, you'll need to cast it as an array:

```
var loc = apiJson.objectForKey("loc") as [AnyObject]
for i in loc {
    println(i["_name"])
}
```

This will print:

```
北京
英国
日本
发过
中国
```

Comment: How to loop json arrays ?